# Rapidminer for finding statistics

Tags: rapidminer, skew, kurtosis

I am a beginner in Rapidminer .
While working on Rapidminer

1. i didn't find how to calculate or get skewness and kurtosis of a attributes   in   an exampleset.
2. I would like to know is there a way to get best fit line for a scatter plot graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For skewness and kurtosis, you could either calculate it yourself using a combination of operators or you could use the R extension and use the `moments` package which contains these functions. I think I would use R.

For the scatter plot question, you could use the `Linear Regression` operator to build a model that fits a straight line. You need to arrange for one of the attributes to be a label that is to be predicted by the other attribute.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. As I'm new to this can you help me with this in more detailed manner .

Comment: No problem. For the R part, you have to install the R extension which is available from the RapidMiner Marketplace. Once you have done this, new operators appear that allow R scripts to be executed within a RapidMiner workflow. Obviously, you would need to know R. For the Linear Regression part, there are many samples included with RapidMiner. One of these is located at the following location in the repository `//Samples/processes/01_Learner/02_LinearRegression` and you can save this with another name to do what you want.